# Is there a database with (Integer) Linear Programming problems/solutions?

Tags: dataset, linear-programming

There are lots of databases of training sets where one can test one's machine learning algorithms. Is there also one where I could test my (Integer) Linear Programming Solver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LP problems there is [NETLIB](http://www.netlib.org/lp/). MIP problems can be found in [MIPLIB](http://miplib.zib.de/). Hans Mittelmann has a collection [here](http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html).